# How do I receive callback from Paypal buy now button using PHP

Tags: php, button, paypal

I am currently testing the buy now button on a PHP website. The transaction is working but I am getting now call back from Paypal to update my database.

Here is the code I have (I have changed urls) :

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="........"
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_CA/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"   border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - la solution de paiement en ligne la plus simple et  la plus sécurisée !">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_CA/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">


<input name="notify_url" value="mypage.php" type="hidden">
</form>
```

For the call back I saw on another website I should receive a $_POST['payment_status']; and a $_POST['invoice'];

Is it true?

Comment: Please look up [IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) services. The source code for PHP is found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/).

Answer (score 8):

`$_POST['payment_status'];` and a `$_POST['invoice'];`

You are correct. After a successful payment, paypal will contact your page at `mypage.php`.
After you verify that it is paypal talking to your page, you can process the `$_POST` variables.

The list of variables that paypal will send you is listed [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/).

Comment: am i using the right way to specify the right page?
<input name="notify_url" value="mypage.php" type="hidden">

Comment: you should use the full public url. `http://mywebsite.com/mypage.php`, if indeed the `mypage.php` is found on the root.

Comment: @DaveChen and how do I know that paypal is that talking to my site? Without using $ _POST ['payment_status']

Comment: You need to verify with paypal.

Comment: What happens if the use takes ages to process the pay pal transaction, let say 30mins ... by the time they come back to my site their reserved order has been cancelled as it took too long. But you would have already accepted the users money ... what do do in this situation?